# How I can set property of object properties?(js)

Tags: javascript, object, defineproperty

I using js and i want set property of object properties

```js
var a=42
Object.defineProperty(this,"a",{value:43} )//Error
```

How I can set property of object properties after defining.

Comment: `a` is not an object but in primitive type. But to set object property you can do `var a = {a: 42}; a[b] = 43;`

Comment: What is `this` here? What is the point of `var a`?

Comment: Information provided is too low. Chaotic question. Please explain it to understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, `a` is a primitive type (`number`). You can just update it how you would any other variable:

```js
var a = 42;
a = 43;
console.log(a);
```

---

If you want an object, you have two choices - define `a` as an object and change the `value` property, or reassign `a` to be an object with a `value` property.

Method one:

```js
var a = {
  value: 42
};
a.value = 43;
console.log(a);
```

Method 2:

```js
var a = 42;
a = {
  value: 43
};
console.log(a);
```

Comment: No,I want set property of variable

Comment: What do you mean @Kayrag?

Answer (score 0):

To extend an object's property in javascript you use the `prototype` proterty that is already possessed by `Object`.

All javascript objects are instances of `Object` and inherit from `Object.prototype`. So you can extend the property of this class to add a property to any other objects in javascript like this:

```
var a = 42;
Object.prototype.getValue = 43;
document.write(a.getValue); // output should be 43.
```

see the jsfiddle sample [here](https://jsfiddle.net/udochify/7d1ovmux/13/).

Answer (score 0):

That is possible with objects such as `Number` :

```js
var a = new Number(42)

a.value = 43

console.log( a.value )
```